# Typo3: How to render the titles of the backend-columns in Fluid/ExtBase?

Tags: typo3, title, backend, typoscript, fluid

I'm not sure if I used the correct terms :D

Let's imagine that my backend-layout looks like this:

```
backend_layout {
   colCount = 1
   rowCount = 1
   rows {
       1 {
           columns {
               1 {
                   name = Baguette
                   colPos = 0
               }
           }
       }
   }   
}
```

I'm looking for a TypoScript which looks kinda like this:

```
[...]
variables {
   title < ****the stuff i'm looking for***
   title.select.where = colPos = 0
}
```

The script should automatically take the name of my backend-column ("Baguette") and save it into the "title"-variable.
Then i can simply add `<f:format.raw> {title} </f:format.raw>` in my template to output it in the frontend.

**Does something like this exist?**

*Btw:* It's necessary to be able to select the colPos since I'm having many columns with many titles to output.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exist. The titles are only known to the backend and are not available in the frontend context.

Actually the frontend does not know anything about the backend grid. All you have in the frontend, is the column number.